# Forward slash / in CSS border radius syntax

Tags: css, syntax, internet-explorer-8, compatibility

Recently I came across following border radius syntax unknown to me:

```
.myClass{
    border-radius: 30% / 20%;
}
```

Can anyone explain the syntax.
And is it compatible with IE8?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-radius) :

> If values are given before and after the slash, then the values before
>   the slash set the horizontal radius and the values after the slash set
>   the vertical radius. If there is no slash, then the values set both
>   radii equally.

As far as the support goes, IE8 doesn't support `border-radius` property be it whatever syntax you write in. There are polyfills available like [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/) if you want to make `border-radius` work on IE8.

You can check on [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius) for `border-radius` support across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp `border-radius` is not compatible with IE8 but IE9.